# Multiple IF expression? How to? Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

How to have multiple IF expressions?
Like this :

```
    If (expression1)&&(expression2)&&...{}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the syntax like so:

```
if ( (1<2) && (2>3) || (100 == 10*10 ) ) {
}
```

One other thing to keep in mind when using multiple expressions within an if statement is the behavior of short circuiting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation